# Symfony 3 nested collection templating with Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

how i can templating nested collection?.

I create templating parent collection with block:

```
{% block _group_match_groupMatchType_entry_row %}
```

In this block i have collection:

```
<div class="js-collection-parrent round text-right" data-prototype="{{ form_row(form.matchResult.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
```

How i can get every entry row of matchResult collection which has parent collection groupMatchType?

GroupMatchType

```
$builder
        ->add('groupMatchType', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => MatchType::class,
            'allow_add'     => true,
            'allow_delete'  => true,
            'by_reference'  => false
        ])
```

MatchType

```
$builder
        ->add('matchResult', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => MatchResultType::class,
            'allow_add'     => true,
            'allow_delete'  => true,
            'by_reference'  => false
        ])
```

And view

```
{% block _group_match_groupMatchType_entry_row %}
   <div class="js-collection-parrent round text-right" data-prototype="{{ form_row(form.matchResult.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}"></div>
{% endblock %}
```

I have to find name of above block (maybe like _group_match_groupMatchType_entry_row_matchResult_entry_row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i solved that. The block should be named

```
_group_match_groupMatchType_entry_matchResult_entry_row
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting all sub-elements in a form on twig is simple:

```
{% for element in form.elements %}
    {# Do something with this element #}
    {# But think that it will represent the form element #}
{% endfor %}
```

real example:

```
{% for movie in form.movies %}
    {{ form_widget(movie.title, {'attr' : {'class':'form-control'}}) }}
    {{ form_row(movie.id) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Don't really know if is what you need, but I believe it's an approach to what you mean.

Comment: That's not what I mean. I have two nested collection with prototype like example on [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-a-collection-prototype)

Comment: Can you post the code of your formTypes and/or view?